# AngularJs refactoring common code in to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring

In angularJs I have two controllers which have one function common.I write a service and put that common method in service.

Which of following is correct way or there is any better way to do this.

1. calls common service by sending `$scope` objects which gets modified

> ```
>   angular.module('app').controller('ACtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, MyCommonService) {
>             $scope.firstObj = {....};
>             //can required more than 4 param
>             MyCommonService.doCommontask(firstObj........);
>         });
> ```

```
        angular.module('app').service('MyCommonService', function(RestService) 
        {
            this.doCommontask = function (firstObje.......) {
                //following call is to service which do rest call and 
                //almost all work is inside the call back.
                RestService.xxxGET().$promise.then(function(data)
                {
                  // firstObje gets and others modified here and need

                  //value to be reflected in view controlled by ACtrl

                  // most of params of docommonTask used here
                });

            };
        });
```

2. calls common service and use `$rootScope` to access obj from `controller` which gets modified

> ```
> angular.module('app').controller('ACtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, MyCommonService) {
>             //though $rootScope, will only used by this controller and,commonService
>
>             $rootScope.firstObj = {....}; 
>             //no param as rootScope is used 
>             MyCommonService.doCommontask();
>         });
> ```

```
    angular.module('app').service('MyCommonService', function($rootScope, RestService) {
        this.doCommontask = function () {
            //following call is to service which do rest call and 
            //almost all work is inside the call back.
            RestService.xxxGET($rootScope.firstObj...).$promise.then(function(data){
              // firstObje gets and others modified here and need
                 value to be reflected in view controlled by ACtrl
              // most of params of docommonTask used here
            });

        };
    });
```

Which one to follow or is there any better way/refactored code which good reason?

Please do suggest best practices for refactoring.

Comment: Plz help editing. some how its not working. my bad :)

Comment: I would go for option 1. provided you do not update the scope directly from the service but use a callback which updates the scope back in the controller. there is NO reason to add needless items to the rootScope... make you components as self contained and isolated as possible

Comment: In the top code segment you have "MyService" when it is actually called "MyCommonService".

Rename "MyService" to "MyCommonService"